# OpenLayers map with custom projection not showing WMS

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, wms

Trying to add to my map an WMS layer with custom projection

When executing, the map does not show any layer.

Custom projection:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:25830","+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
register(proj4);
const customproj = getProjection('EPSG:25830');
```

WMS Layer:

```
var layer = 
  new TileLayer({
    source: new TileWMS({
      url: 'https://idena.navarra.es/ogc/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'catastro'},
      projection: customproj
    })
  });
```

Map:

```
var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [layer],
  view: new View({
    projection: customproj,
    center: fromLonLat([-1.629950,42.63]),
    zoom: 9
  })
});
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: The map iis currently centered to default EPSG:3857 coordinates, it should be `center: fromLonLat([-1.629950,42.63], customproj),`

Comment: You are right! Answer the question for marking it as solution @Mike

Comment: Not sure it's correct to say custom projection for an EPSG defined CRS https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map iis currently centered to default EPSG:3857 coordinates, it should be center: `fromLonLat([-1.629950,42.63], customproj),`